# Second to most recent date with date duplicates

Tags: sql-server, date

I am trying to retrieve the 2nd to the most recent date for appointments. I utilized ROW_NUM_DESC to retrieve the most recent date. So, the where clause is displayed as ROW_NUM_DESC = 1.

My dilemma is that the column where I pull the date from has duplications of dates. So, ROW_NUM_DESC = 2 is not an accurate representation of the 2nd most recent value.

Can not use the following with reasons:

1. DISTINCT in the select statement. 
   Reason: there is another field listed- department name. I want a list of     department names per dates.
2. GROUP BY- requires me to list all columns from the select statement like     department name. 
   Reason: Again,I want a list of all department names per dates.
3. DATEPART- requires an integer for NUMBER in syntax. Can I do convert from integer is a datetime greater than the date listed in ROW_NUM_DESC?

Any help is appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dense_rank with partition and filter by 2 as below:

```
Select * from
   ( Select *, RowN = dense_rank() over(partition by idcolumn order by yourDate desc from Yourtable ) a
Where a.RowN = 2
```

Here Partition by idcolumn you can use if required to get top 2nd recent appointment for individual idcolumn or other column or remove

Comment: hi @Kannan Kandasamy ! thank you for the answer. my apologies if you answered this part of the question. my problem is there are duplicate dates in the column. So for example; 1 = 07/12/17, 2 = 07/12/17, 3 = 07/09/17. So filtering it to RowN = 2 will return the most recent date as well.

Comment: first line of text should now read *"You can use DENSE_RANK with partition"*

Comment: Yep, still this is issue if two records get same second date, it depends on OP's requirement, then OP might require to use top 1 if that is requirement

Comment: Thank you Kannan! I adjusted my query to this and waiting patiently for the results.